# Android Studio dependency confusion - Lombok

Tags: gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, lombok

I was trying to integrate Lombok library to a non-Android module on Android Studio.

At first this is what I added to the build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok-maven', version: '1.16.10.0'
```

This is the same syntax I always use for everything else (spring, etc) and it works just fine.

Everything compiled fine but the Lombok jar simply was not fetched no matter what I did (clean/rebuild/restart IDE, etc.).

Eventually I changed the dependency line to:

```
compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
```

and then finally the jar was fetched properly.

I don't really understand what's going on here. The first dependency line is what I got from the official maven repository. The second line I just happen to stumble upon around the web.

Attempting to use the 2nd line with the newest version (1.16.10.0) fails to compile, stating that no such jar exists.

I am sure I am missing some fundamental principles here with gradle or something else. 
I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on things as I have wasted lots of time and effort on this silly issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which repositories are defined in the script?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think these:
`buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

    }`

Answer (score 2):

I think you just misspelled the version - the latest version is 1.6.10, not 1.6.10.0.

So `compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10'` will work.

Comment: You are right about the version, thanks. It worked, but it's not what truly bothers me. I am more concerned about the syntax 'compile' vs 'compile group'. The latter, which doesn't work, is the one I get from the maven repository's official website. Whenever I am need of a dependency I always go there and simply copy and paste it to my build.gradle and get the library. I am trying to understand why this time it doesn't work, and only the 'compile' syntax works. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, there are two artifacts in the Maven: 'lombok-maven' and 'lombok'. I believe 'lombok' is the one you need, as 'lombok-maven' doesn't have any files to download.

Comment: I see. That's so weird. Usually I search from the same archive (maven official repository) and add what I find from there. This all seems very strange to me. Thanks anyway for helping Alexiy I appreciate it a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized my confusion. I didn't notice I was trying to add the lombok **PLUGIN** and not the lombok project itself.

In my defense, it is quite confusing (especially when searching at 2am ;)). This is what I should have used:[Maven Repository - Correct lombok dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.16.10)

This is what I was wrongfully trying to use:

[Maven Repository - Lombok Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-maven/1.16.10.0)

Which is actually the first thing that pops up when searching "Maven Lombok" on Google.

Comment: You know you can use http://search.maven.org/ for searching? For example, this is the search result for 'lombok' - http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.projectlombok%22